# Creating a list from a sequence generating function (fibonacci)

Tags: python, sequence, fibonacci

I'm trying to create a second function which puts all the numbers from a sequence into a list. Here is my attempt:

```py
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    if n == 1 :
        print(a)
    if n < 1 :
        print("pick a number greater than or equal to 1")
    else:
        print(a)
        print(b)

        for i in range(2, n):
            c = a + b
            a = b
            b = c
            print(c)

def fib_list(fib(n)):
    list = [fib(n)]
    for i == n:
        print(list)
```

Comment: Why `for i == n:` (in last function) ?

Comment: Create a list `numbers = []` and store the values via `numbers.append(c)`. In the end, `return numbers`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'd do it backwards if I were you - make a function that does the list (or better yet, a generator) and have another function that `print`s the results.

Comment: @gusifer98 I'd like to draw attention to the fact you created a variable called `list`, and that's discouraged because there's a function called `list()` (you're **shadowing** the function). I've added this as a comment because it's not directly related to your question thoough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are going for the following with your code:

```py
def fib_list(n):
    list = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        list.append(fib(i))
    print(list)
```

A more efficient way to generate the fibonacci sequence is by using dynamic programming. The answer of Chandler Bong shows you how.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple like this without the need to a second function:

```
def fib(n):
    fibList = [0, 1]
    for i in range(2, n):
        fibList.append(fibList[i-2] + fibList[i-1])
    print(fibList)
```

sample input:

`fib(7)`

output:

`[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]`

This is an efficient way to solve the fibbonaci problem using dynamic programming.